# How to parse json value from server, and display it in tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview

```
  "Names":[  
  {  
     "type":"Name",
     "id":{  
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[  
           80.26483,
           13.08891
        ]
     },
     "properties":{  
       "region":"Tamil Nadu",
        "region_gid":"whosonfirst:region:85672245",
        "county":"Chennai",
        "county_gid":"whosonfirst:county:890505403",
        "label":"Chennai, India"
     }
  },
  {  
     "type":"Name",
     "id":{  
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[  
           80.27847,
           13.08784
        ]
     },




 for(NSDictionary * dict in autocompletedata)
             {
                 Autodata *data = [[Autodata alloc]init];

                 NSMutableArray *coordinates =[dict valueForKey:@"geometry"];
                 NSMutableArray *propertiesarray = [dict valueForKey:@"properties"];


                 for(NSDictionary *properties_dict in propertiesarray)
                 {
                     data.searchterm = [properties_dict objectForKey:@"label"];
                 }
                 NSLog(@"searchterm%@",coordinates);
                  NSLog(@"coordinates%@",propertiesarray);


                 [autodataarray addObject:data];

             }
```

Parse json value from server and display it in tableview cell.

I need to show the label and coordinates, region in tableview cell.

However, I have an error. I don't know how to parse it. I was thinking perhaps I can save the id and properties in different array, and from that I can get value of coordinates and label.

Comment: can you show ur full JSON response

Comment: Updated some grammar and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *YourArray =[Json objectForKey:@"Names"];

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
NSString *strlabel =[[[YourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"properties"]objectForKey:@"label"];

NSString *strregion =[[[YourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"properties"]objectForKey:@"region"];

NSArray *cordintateArray =[[[YourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]ojectForKey:@"id"]objectForKey:@"coordinates"];
}
```

Comment: Always Your Welcome @diva

Answer (score 0):

**success from webservice**

```
yourArray=[dictDashboardData objectForKey:@"Names"];

[yourTableView reloadData];
```

**table veiw method**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return yourArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//...

NSDictionary *dictData = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.yourLabel.text=[dictData objectForKey:@"type"];
cell.yourLabel.text=[dictData objectForKey:@"id"];
    cell.yourLabel.text=[[dictData objectForKey:@"id"]objectForKey:@"type"];
cell.yourLabel.text=[[dictData objectForKey:@"id"]objectForKey:@"coordinates"];
cell.yourLabel.text=[dictData objectForKey:@"properties"];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.Array1 = JSON.object(forKey: "Names") as! NSArray
            for i in 0..<self.Array.count {
                let item = self.Array[i] as! [String: AnyObject]
               //declare Object
                let SampleDetails = SampleObjectModel()
                SampleDetails.Name = ApiClients.sharedInstance.nullremove(value:item["type"]as AnyObject) as! String
                                               self.Array2.append(SampleDetails)

            }
```

**//tableview delegate**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
          let cell = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as!tableviewcell
       //import objectModel and get the data
        let sampleObject = SampleModel.Array2[indexPath.row]
        cell.Namelabel.text = sampleObject.Name

     }
```